# Clustering in Amazon ec2 using Starcluster

Tags: cluster-computing, starcluster

Is it possible to deploy instances from AMI to multiple zones in Amazon EC2 using starcluster?

Can anyone give me your feedback on this please?

I need to deploy instances to various Zones in Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In the addnode command, there is a flag just for that.

```
-z ZONE, --availability-zone=ZONE
```

In the load balancer however you can't. I have a [fork of StarCluster](https://github.com/datacratic/StarCluster/) that enables it though. When you launch it, you specify --ignore-grp. It's only useful when you work with spot instances as it will bid in the cheapest zone.

This fork also supports multiple zone into a VPC, which is also handy.